# Gzip is not working with dynmaic URL

Tags: php, gzip

i am using GZIP for the compression and its working fine but the problem came when the URL's are dynamic (e.g Default/template_css.php?w=310&h=237&sw=200&ct=fpss-container2). I am using Php .

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate "the problem" in more detail. What happens? What happens not? Try to elaborate in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective.

Comment: i tested the site on webpagetest.org and it shows that this type of URL(/template_css.php?w=310&h=237&sw=200&ct=fpss-container2) are not gzipped  . Thanks

Comment: *How* have you configured/used GZIP? A bit more detail please. "It doesn't work" gives nothing to work with. It would be nice if you post the *minimum* required PHP code to reproduce this problem so that we can in fact just copy'n'paste'n'run it to see the same problem (most of us would just *read* the code, but you get [the point](http://sscce.org)).

Answer (score 1):

Only use gzip when there's this line in the http-header:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: but how ? should i place this in .htaccess ?

Comment: This isn't a valid answer. @vipinsahu: you need to elaborate more about the problem.

Comment: @BalusC: I know it's not a real answer to his question, but it's probably a solution to his problem :-)

Comment: @vipinsahu: With http_get_request_headers() you can get the http-header.